# Upgrade MS VS2013 to MS VS2015 Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

Both Question and Solution included here.

When opening a Microsoft Windows Application MS VS2013 C# Professional in MS VS2015 C# Professional, the following error displayed:
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

In VS2015, under Solution Explorer, under References, for Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, the paths were missing under their Properties.  The paths are not editable.

To solve this problem, under References, delete Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.  Then re-add these references (found under Extensions).  The paths were automatically entered, and the compiling errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to include the Microsoft ReportViewer control in your project is to install it via the NuGet package manager.  It *should* keep track of the references and their paths automatically.